# Performance Test SF on IPad

Tags: performance

i need your help and support on an important topic. We have build on SF a new sales solution which will go live within the next months. Every morning I have a data synchronisation on the IPad. So data will be moved from SAP backend over the SF App to the IPads. Therefore I would like to do a performance test for this. According to my understanding SF gurantees performance but SF KPIs does not necessarily means this fits to my enterprise´s KPIs. Therefore I am wondering if there is a tool to be able to manage those kind of test e.g. for 500 users in parallel especially for the case descirbed above.

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to performance test Salesforce. In fact, it wouldn't go very well for you if you tried to stress test salesforce. Salesforce will terminate your tests if they see you pulling too many resources. It is a cloud based platform and they don't allow any customer of any size the privilege of jeopardizing other customers performance for their own sake.

To ease your mind:

> **Do you need to stress test the Force.com platform?**
>
> No. The Force.com platform serves over 1 billion transactions daily
>   with an average response time of under 300 milliseconds, and
>   salesforce.com tests and monitors the platform to ensure that it has
>   excess capacity.
>
> You should definitely take advantage of the platform’s efficiency–but
>   not by writing inefficient code. Salesforce.com guards against highly
>   inefficient code by using governor limits, which help ensure both that
>   your users have a consistent application experience and that resources
>   are available to all salesforce.com customers. (One limit, the Apex
>   Apex script statement limit, is being phased out in the Winter ’14
>   release, but its original reason for existing was the same.)
>
> Your goal should be to use load testing instead of stress testing. If
>   you try to stress test, you’re likely to reach governor limits or have
>   salesforce.com terminate your tests so they don’t affect shared
>   resources on the multitenant Force.com platform. Performance test your
>   anticipated loads instead.

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/09/performance-testing-force-com-application.html